# Using Fiddler with MVC - Getting 401s

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, fiddler, http-status-code-401

I have fiddler installed and I'm running an MVC3 app through visual studio.  Whenever I try to hit the MVC page with fiddler (localhost:28267) I get a 401.  How can I determine what's causing this?  The page loads fine through IE/VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

401 means that Fiddler fails to properly negotiate NTLM credentials. Check it with Firebug network console, you'll probably get the same behavior.

Comment: That's not quite right. A HTTP/401 is the server's demand that the client provide credentials (see the WWw-Authenticate response header). A HTTP/403 is typically returned to suggest that the client's credentials were invalid.

Comment: It turns out all I needed was to set the Automatically Authenticate setting in fiddler.  Thanks :)

Comment: @EricLaw I didn't say the credentials were invalid, I said the negotiation failed.